# Binding C++ and V8 Javascript from Google

Tags: c++, javascript, scripting

The examples are quite challenging to grasp if you are still getting your head around other things, so the simplest example would be great.

Is there a simpler example?

Comment: I included V8 into my game some months before. I think [the code](https://github.com/ComputerGame/GraphicsApplication/blob/terrain/Application/helper/script.h#L15) is quite easy to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some links :

1) A series of tutorials i wrote : https://github.com/underscorediscovery/v8-tutorials

2) CProxyV8 extends on the point/line samples by using their binding code

3) v8Juice is also a binding system for v8, has some simpler examples

4) Find other v8 projects and have a look inside their code (if possible)

5) Ask on gamedev.stackexchange.com

6) Ask on the v8 channel on iRC, freenode server

Comment: You might want to reconsider your choice of grey-on-grey for your blog. The code comments are unreadable and with subpixel hinting on a 1024x768 screen the code itself is also almost unreadable.

Comment: I'll adjust the css for the comments, thanks. Weirdly enough i don't know anyone using 1024x768 ;P Not since i posted has anyone mentioned it being a problem - but thanks for the feedback. I updated the CSS to a blue color. Hope that helps legibility.

Answer (score 3):

I think [this](http://syskall.com/how-to-roll-out-your-own-javascript-api-with) is the simplest working one I could find ([github link](https://github.com/olalonde/jsnotify)). It teaches you how to get V8 up and running and then creates an Alert function in C++ that gets exposed to JavaScript.

Cheers.

Comment: Link is broken (4/2015).

Answer (score 1):

I've been slowly working on a pygame alternative based on V8.

Although the project is stalled at the moment, the code is still up on [Github](https://github.com/qard/jsgame).

Have a look at the bindings files and jsgame.cpp for some examples. Particularly, JSGame::initialize().